# Difference between a ban and lifetime suspension?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

Won't link, but there is a person for whom

> The suspension period ends on Mar 18 '92 at 16:28

Why bother issuing 70+ year long suspension instead of outright giving a ban hammer? Could it be a mod made a typo?

Comment: lifetime bans dont exist on se/so

Comment: Related from über meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319634/why-not-perma-ban-instead-of-suspend-an-account-for-275-years

Comment: Post bans are issued automatically by the system in case of multiple low quality contributions. Suspensions are issued by moderators.

Comment: Mods can only suspend for a year. To go beyond that you need a CM. CM's don't make typos.

Comment: @rene https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8488660#8488660

Comment: That's nowt.  Some users have been banned for 3000 years.

Comment: He got ban until 2292. No one knows, exactly for what. His suspensions started for his physics.stackexchange.com activities. Insulting a Nobel Prize winner to that he left the site, was probably among the reasons. No more is known about, what others he did.

Comment: Btw, I tracked him on out-of-site channels, but he was unresponsive. Possibly he did not get the contact message.

Comment: @rene CMs make typos, but they can fix them. :-) But that was not a typo. He made some CM really, really annoyed, and he typed "99999" into a textbox. I tried to find him once, but I could not get a response from him, although I would be really curious on his version of the story.